# Why does the Kohen Gadol say "Hashem" rather than the Tetragrammaton

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, shemos-sacred-names

In the Avoda, the tefilla of the Kohen Gadol begins thus:

> וכך היה אומר: אנא השם

While the ineffable name is used at the end of the tefilla, why is the name "HaShem" used to preface the tefilla rather than the tetragrammaton?

Comment: Are you asking about the Chazan-nowadays or the Kohein Gadol-backintheday?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Why the tefillah says "השם" rather than the tetragrammaton. That is my question.

Comment: (Re your comment.) Whose _t'fila_? The _kohen_'s or the _shatz_'s?

Comment: The way it seemed from reading both the Hebrew and the English was that it referred to the tefillah which is quoted from the K"G, said by the sha"tz.